# Outlook 2016 macro for changing a selection to New Times Roman 12 point italic

Tags: vba, outlook, selection

I need a macro for Outlook 2016 that can change a selection to: font = Times New Roman, Size = 12 and Italic.

I created a macro on the fly in an older version of Outlook that worked fine.  I also created one that "undid" what I had done.

I also created a macro on the fly in Word 2016 for doing the above.  I tried pasting it into Outlook.  I also tried editing it with guesses.  Nothing worked.

Don't have any current code.

Verdana 10 normal text should change to Times New Roman 12 italic.

Comment: I tried the code below which I found on the internet and which I amended slightly.  When I tried running it I got the message: "Compile error.  User-defined type not defined" when it hit the line, "Dim objWord As Word.Application".

Comment: Search the site for "User-defined type not defined" and you should get the information you need to run the code you found.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main ways for working with bodies in Outlook:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The `Inspector` class provides the [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an instance of the `Document` class from the Word object model which represents the message body. Outlook uses Word as an email editor. So, you can use the Word object model to deal with the message body in Outlook.

You can read more about that in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) .

Comment: Thank you for your response.  However, it doesn't help me at all.  I have programmed (years ago) in C but when I look at Visual Basic code it looks like Martian to me.  What I was looking for was specific VB code to accomplish my task.  Your answer is gibberish to me.